# How to connect to AWS RedShift with Tableau desktop software?

Tags: postgresql, tableau-api, amazon-redshift

I want to use Tableau to retrieve data from AWS RedShift and then generate reports, I tried to use PostgreSQL driver downloaded from Tableau website, but cannot establish the connection.

Any one knows how to do it?

Comment: "cannot establish the connection". Details? Error message? Driver version? Did you try with the stock PgJDBC driver?

Comment: Can you double check security group associated with the cluster? You can try SqlWorkbench to verify configuration and then use JDBC connecter to make connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on [Tableau's blog](http://www.tableausoftware.com/about/blog/2013/2/amazon-redshift-connector-preview), the Tableau connector hasn't been released yet, but you can contact your account manager to try out a preview version.

That's what my team has done, and it worked without a hitch.

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide an update, I believe the RedShift Connector has been released for v7 of Tableau Desktop, but is still in preview for v8.  We have found it to be much easier for connecting to our RedShift cluster so far.

Answer (score 2):

The generic ODBC connector also works, you get an interesting pop-up saying certain functions might not behave as expected but we have not encountered any issues using it.

Also the redshift connector for Tableau 8 is out now in release.

Answer (score 1):

It's now possible to connect Amazon Redshift with Tableau.

To connect:

1. Open Tableau Desktop Application and select **Amazon Redshift** from the list of servers to connect.
2. Populate the following fields in the pop-up as shown below:

[image]

where

> **Server:** the URL to the Redshift instance
>
> **Port:** the port on which it listens to
>
> **Database:** the DB to connect to

(the above 3 information is available under the ***Cluster Database Properties*** section within the ***Configuration*** tab in your AWS Console.)

> **Username and Password:** credentials authenticated to connect and query the schema and the underlying tables in above mentioned DB

Click on Sign In to allow Tableau to connect to the Amazon Redshift instance.